# How to run a test which needs two devices using Appium

Tags: appium

I understand that in order to control multiple devices using Appium i need to start multiple Appium servers with different ports. But, i am unable to get how can i target part of my tests to a specific device when multiple devices are connected to host computer.

I understand, below are the two configurations i need to do in order to handle multiple devices connected to a computer.

1. port setting: e.g. 4723 in below webdriver initialization

   `webdriver.Remote("http://127.0.0.1:4723/wd/hub", desired_caps_first_device)`
2. desired_caps for different devices.e.g.

   desired_caps_first_device = {'platformName': 'Android', 'platformVersion': '7.0',
   'deviceName': 'gts210velte', 'appPackage':'package_name', 'appActivity':'activity_name'}

I have two Android devices are connected to a machine and both are of same model(deviceName). I understand that i can create two driver instances but how would Appium know which instance is for which physical device? In other words how should i differentiate between the two devices in the code so that i know a piece of code is going to be executed on a particular device out of the two connected to a machine?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found that there is a property called `udid` which can be assigned `adb` device id to target specific android device when multiple devices are connected to host machine.

e.g.

```
device_caps_first_device =  {'platformName': 'Android', 'platformVersion': '7.0', 'udid': 'xxxxxxx', 'deviceName': 'gts210velte', 'appPackage':'package_name', 'appActivity':'activity_name'}

device_caps_second_device =  {'platformName': 'Android', 'platformVersion': '7.0', 'udid': 'yyyyyyy', 'deviceName': 'gts210velte', 'appPackage':'package_name', 'appActivity':'activity_name'}
```

udid is defined as Unique device identifier of the connected physical device at http://appium.io/docs/en/writing-running-appium/caps/

Answer (score 3):

Use the desired capability of `udid` with the ID of the device you need to map  to whichever server you like.

The ID for the device can be found using the following command:

```
$ adb devices
```

Answer (score 0):

Two similar kind of devices are distinguished by udid.

Here is a sample script to make connection with 1 device, you can have a look on this and modify it to suite ur needs for multiple devices.

Example is self explanatory.

https://automationlab0000.wordpress.com/2018/08/21/first-automation-script-using-robot-framework/